# "Whatever you say" and "Whatever you may say"

Tags: modal-verbs, clauses, grammaticality-in-context

I would like to ask a question on the usage of "whatever you may say".

Let's suppose I would like to say something like:

- "Whatever you may say, I cannot stop now."

I would like to convey the meaning that regardless of what you might say, I cannot stop now.

In this case, which expression of following three is grammatical?

> 1. "Whatever you say,"
> 2. "Whatever you may say"
> 3. "Whatever you might(would) say"

Comment: Sentence two sounds the most correct.

Answer (score 1):

All of them are grammatical. However, another option that (at least in my experience) is more common, is **"Say what you want, I can't stop now."**